# C3 js - Prevent page scroll to top when chart is regenerated

Tags: c3.js

Is it possibile to prevent page scroll to page top when chart is regenerated ?

After the page is loaded with C3 chart, I scrolled to bottom of the page and I have auto generating chart event with latest data for every 10 seconds dring this time scrollbar is moving to top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `c3.generate()` to load the latest data.
Why don't you use `chart.load()`? This would solve your problem.

```
//call generate only once
var chart = c3.generate(..)

//refresh your data whenever you want
chart.load({
      columns: [ ['data1', 230, 190, 300, 500, 300, 400] ]
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was due to the page height changing when the chart was destroyed/redrawn, it was causing the page to go from being a scrollable height to all in one window and had the affect of scrolling to the top. I fixed the issue by **setting the min-height of the div containg the chart** to be the same size as the drawn chart, so the page was always going to be the same height whether the chart was there or being regenerated.